# How can I auto-expand my menu on responsive version of site (twitter bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

My twitter bootstrap website is www.airterrariums.com.au

How can I have the menu auto-expand instead of collapsing when in responsive mode.

Comment: please share your code or make an fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Just add "in" to the class list of this div:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

So that it becomes:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse in">
```

Comment: Do I add it in the CSS? Or as a template modifier? Because I cant find the .php file that holds the code..

Answer (score 0):

According to the Bootstrap 4 [site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) you add the `show` class to the nav-bar. 
This will auto expand your navigation bar. 
Example:

```
<div class="collapse show navbar-collapse">
```